# How to create a tree-view in vue-js with clickable components opening up a vue-js modal?

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js

I want to create a tree-view component in Vue-JS to display my JSON data. But I have an additional requirement where I need to launch a VueJS modal on clicking any of the data fields of JSON view. I looked up at several `npm modules` that does display data in tree-view but I am not sure how to modify them to make them clickable and launch `vue-js modal`.
This is the code I am currently using to display tree-view but none of the fields are clickable.

`assets.vue`

```
    <template>

  <div>  

        <h1>The Assets Page</h1>
        <!--<p>{{response}}</p>-->
        <tree-view v-on:click="openGroupModal()" :data="response._embedded.assets" :options="{maxDepth: 0, rootObjectKey: 'Assets'}"></tree-view>
      </div>

</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import GroupModal from '../assets/assetdetails.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
Vue.use(VModal, { dynamic: true })

export default {
  name: 'service',
  data () {
   return {
   response: [],
   errors: []
   }
   },
   
 created () {
      this.callRestService()
    },
 methods: {
   callRestService () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/assets')
   .then(response => {
   // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
   this.response = response.data
   })
   .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  })
},
openGroupModal(){

  this.$modal.show(GroupModal,
  {
      draggable: true,
      resizable: true,
      scrollable: true,
      height: "auto",
      width:"50%"
    })
}
 }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

`main.js`

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
import App from './App.vue'
import TreeView from 'vue-json-tree-view'

import { routes } from './routes';


Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VModal, { dynamic: true })
Vue.use(TreeView)
//Vue.config.productionTip = false

const router = new VueRouter({

  routes  
});


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I tried Jacob's answer but that didn't help me launch the modal. I tried this:

```
<template>

  <div>  

        <h1>The Assets Page</h1>
        <!--<p>{{response}}</p>-->
        <div @click.capture="openGroupModal($event)">
        <tree-view :data="response._embedded.assets" :options="{maxDepth: 0, rootObjectKey: 'Assets'}"></tree-view>
        </div>
      </div>

</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import GroupModal from '../assets/assetdetails.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
Vue.use(VModal, { dynamic: true })

export default {
  name: 'service',
  data () {
   return {
   response: [],
   errors: []
   }
   },
   
 created () {
      this.callRestService()
    },
 methods: {
   callRestService () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/assets')
   .then(response => {
   // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
   this.response = response.data
   })
   .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  })
},
openGroupModal($event){
  console.log("The console message",$event.target);
  this.$modal.show(GroupModal,
  {
      draggable: true,
      resizable: true,
      scrollable: true,
      height: "auto",
      width:"50%"
    })
}
 }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Do you mean you wish to open the modal on a route? IE: deep linking in lands you on an open modal?

Comment: Not really on route. Just pop it up on an onClick event on a particular node of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well.. a div container can work for you

use @click.capture. (once `.capture` is added, an event targeting an inner element is handled here before being handled by that element, from [Vue doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers))

and you can get exactly which element has been clicked on by using `$event.target`

e.g.

```
<template>
  <div @click.capture="openGroupModal($event)">
    <tree-view :data="{1:1,2:{a:'a'}}" :options="{maxDepth: 3}"></tree-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  methods:{
    openGroupModal($event){
      console.log($event.target);
      // other codes for showing modal and etc...
    }
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Tested on HelloWorld.vue component in https://codesandbox.io/s/nkwk2k095l

Comment: Let me try it out. This should make all the nodes of the tree clickable you mean?

Comment: That didn't work. I do get which element is being clicked but I am not able to launch the modal on clicking any node. Check my update for the code I tried.

Comment: @CodeHunter `import VModal from 'vue-js-modal' ;Vue.use(VModal, { dynamic: true })` should be done in `main.js`, not in the component.

Comment: @CodeHunter I'm able to get the modal working in https://codesandbox.io/s/4x4vxx9984

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I was also able to get it working using npm vue-tree-harlow package which provides you to deal with node-click elements and you can trigger the individual events on each node.